# Accessing Elements In Doctrine Query Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Doctrine query, where the "JOIN p.product pr" is joining in the Product Table and all of its info (id, name, qty, status, created, updated, deletedAt, etc...)

Custom function in my repository class...

```
 $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('
        SELECT      p
        FROM        WIC\PurchaseOrderBundle\Entity\PurchaseOrderProductsStatus p
        JOIN        p.product pr
        WHERE       p.inventoryLocation = :id
        AND         p.account = :account_id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->setParameter('account_id', $account_id);

    try{
        return $query->getArrayResult();
    }catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
        return $e;
    }
```

In my controller I am sending the array into a twig template...

```
 $productActions = My custom function query listed above which returns array

 return array(
        'heading' => 'Inventory Staging Location',
        'productActions' => $productActions,
    );
```

In my Twig template I am now trying to loop through the records...

```
 {% for productAction in productActions %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ productAction.product.sku }}</td>
                            <td>{{ productAction.product.name }}</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
```

I am getting this error...

```
 Key "product" for array with keys "id, qty, status, created, updated, deletedAt" does not exist in ...
```

**What Am I doing wrong?**

When I do my query by doing a ->findBy() everything seems to work fine. **This array works when sent to the twig template**

```
 $productActions = $em->getRepository('WICPurchaseOrderBundle:PurchaseOrderProductsStatus')->findBy(array(
            "inventoryLocation"=>$inventoryLocation,
            "account"=>$account_id,
        ));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to request **pr** in SELECT part ;)

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('
        SELECT      p, pr
        FROM        WIC\PurchaseOrderBundle\Entity\PurchaseOrderProductsStatus p
        JOIN        p.product pr
        WHERE       p.inventoryLocation = :id
        AND         p.account = :account_id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->setParameter('account_id', $account_id);

    try{
        return $query->getArrayResult();
    }catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
        return $e;
    }
```

Comment: LOL, its always something so little like this :) Thanks for your help!